# default value of a variable at the time of declaration in C# and VB?

Tags: variables, default, declaration

Can anybody tell me what is the default value of a variable at the time of declaration in C# and vb??

Answer (score 54):

In c# you can use the default keyword to determine default values.

For example:

```
default(bool)
default(int)
default(int?)
```

Comment: Nice "generic" way to get the information. Should be accepted as answer !

Comment: in 2019, default is enough.

Answer (score 26):

Do you mean a (method) variable? or a field (on an instance or type)?

For a method-level variable (in C# at least) it is irrelevant, since "definite assignment" means that you *must* give it a value before you can read it.

Fields default to the bitwise zero state:

- for reference types (including string) that means null
- for `Nullable<T>` (`int?` etc) that means null
- for numerics that means 0
- for enums that means 0 **even if there is no 0-valued enum defined**
- for bools that means false
- for DateTime, that means the same as MinValue
- for other structs, you'll have to check their documentation, but it will be a (hopefully sensible) "zero/empty" value

Answer (score 14):

This can be found in MSDN:

Visual Basic .NET defines the following primitive types:

The integral value types Byte (1-byte unsigned integer), Short (2-byte signed integer), Integer (4-byte signed integer), and Long (8-byte signed integer). These types map to System.Byte, System.Int16, System.Int32, and System.Int64, respectively. **The default value of an integral type is equivalent to the literal 0.**

The floating-point value types Single (4-byte floating point) and Double (8-byte floating point). These types map to System.Single and System.Double, respectively. **The default value of a floating-point type is equivalent to the literal 0.**

The Decimal type (16-byte decimal value), which maps to System.Decimal. The default value of decimal is equivalent to the literal 0D.

The Boolean value type, which represents a truth value, typically the result of a relational or logical operation. The literal is of type System.Boolean. **The default value of the Boolean type is equivalent to the literal False.**

The Date value type, which represents a date and/or a time and maps to System.DateTime. **The default value of the Date type is equivalent to the literal # 01/01/0001 12:00:00AM #.**

The Char value type, which represents a single Unicode character and maps to System.Char. **The default value of the Char type is equivalent to the constant expression ChrW(0).**

The String reference type, which represents a sequence of Unicode characters and maps to System.String. **The default value of the String type is a null reference.**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711900.aspx

Comment: Thanks everyone.. My problem has been resolved. Your responses are appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

The C# language specification states that for **value types** the default value is the same as the one assigned by the default constructor and for **reference types** it is null:

So the value types default constructor values are:

> For all simple-types, the default
>   value is the value produced by a bit
>   pattern of all zeros:
>
> - For sbyte, byte, short, ushort, int,    uint, long, and ulong, the
>     default    value is 0.
> - For char, the default value is    '\x0000'. For float, the default
>     value is 0.0f.
> - For double, the default value is
>     0.0d. For decimal, the default value is
>     0.0m. For bool, the default value is false.
> - For an enum-typeE, the default value    is 0.
> - For a struct-type, the default value    is the value produced by
>     setting all    value type fields to
>     their default    value and all
>     reference type fields    to null.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691142(v=VS.71).aspx

The string is not a value type.

Answer (score 4):

Depends on the type of the variable. If the type can be null then it's default value will be null. Nullable types will all start null.

- Complex types (String, StringBuilder) = null
- Numeric types (int, decimal, double, byte) = 0
- Boolean = false
- DateTime = DateTime.MinValue (01/01/0001 00:00:00)

You can set an initial value using:

> string s1 = "test";
>
> Dim s1 As String = "test"