# Any difference between the following two

Tags: c#, .net

1) `A a;`
 2) `A a = null;`

Is there any difference?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589920/default-value-of-a-variable-at-the-time-of-declaration-in-c-and-vb

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a local variable, absolutely - the first isn't definitely assigned, the second is. For example:

```
void DoesntCompile()
{
    A a;
    string x = a.ToString(); // Can't use a - it's not definitely assigned
}

void CompilesButGoesBang()
{
    A a = null;
    string x = a.ToString(); // Throws a NullReferenceException
}
```

For an field (static or instance), if `A` is a reference type, it probably doesn't make any difference. I *could* write a program to demonstrate a difference in the case where it's a static variable, but it would rely on executing the static type initializer twice using reflection... nasty.

If you could give more context about why you're asking, that would really help.

Comment: I just want to understand why C# does no default null when you declaring reference type. I think if declaring a value type, it should have default value, right?

Comment: @user496949: No, not for local variables. There are some odd things you can do with mutable structs, assigning fields to "empty" variables first, but if you just use something like `int` you'll see the exact same behaviour with local variables as with string local variables.

Comment: @user496949 as a *variable*, no: not even value-types have an initial value (although there is an edge-case way of *assigning* all the fields of an unassigned struct, but that is messy anyways, and demands mutability). The simpler answer is "variables have no initial value; fields get the type's default value"

Comment: But it is defaulting to null. But it gives you one more layer of protection by telling you it might be wrong to have default value.

Comment: @Euphoric: Without performing weird reflection-fu, you can't tell *what* the "default" value is for a local variable. It might be some bit pattern meaning "this is neither null nor a valid reference". C# itself makes no guarantees. Now the Microsoft C# compiler for .NET *does* actually generate code which will basically set it to null, but that's an implementation detail. It's more logical to think of it as not having a value, from a language point of view.

Answer (score 2):

In C#, variables default according to the rules listed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691171%28v=VS.71%29.aspx).

The main difference between those two is that for case 2 the variable can be considered "definitely assigned".  Depending on how the variable is going to be used, it may need to be definitely assigned before the compiler will allow certain operations.  Please see [this note](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691172%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) on definite assignment.

Comment: I just want to understand the following, since each type has default value, why compiler prevent you to use the unassigned local variables.

Comment: The references are *right*, but it may be time to switch away from the VS 2003 docs...

Comment: @user496949 both answers have already told you; "definite assignment" - this is demanded (for variables) in the spec.