# Should we set variables to null, false and create new objects when initializing?

Tags: c#, null

I was on the IBM page looking for some filenet example code for .NET and I found this:

```
namespace CESample
{
    // Represents the connection with the Content Engine.
    public class CEConnection
    {
        private IDomain domain;
        private IObjectStoreSet ost;
        private ArrayList osNames;
        private String domainName;
        private bool isCredentialsEstablished;

        // Constructor
        public CEConnection()
        {
            domain = null;
            ost = null;
            osNames = new ArrayList();
            domainName = null;
            isCredentialsEstablished = false;
        }

        //... other methods
```

Its this alright, to set always every variable to null while creating an object? And How about the bool and new ArrayList()? Is that how we should do that? Setting boolean always to false?

Comment: Collections are generally tested by `Count > 0` and not by `!= null`, that's why they are typically initialised. Setting a bool to false is to a secure approach, to avoid false-positives. Everything else would be null by default, anyway.

Comment: [default value of a variable at the time of declaration in C# and VB](http://stackoverflow.com/a/590031/284240)

Comment: @AndreCalil: `isCredentialsEstablished` is `false` by default, as `default(bool) == false`. Explicitly setting it to `false` provides no benefit whatsoever.

Comment: @Andre: As per Jons advice, I would suggest using `Any()` instead of `Count` (which is not available on IEnumerable) or `Count()` which might actually loop over all items compared to `Any()` which does not.

Comment: @Laoujin It's fine, but it'll throw an exception if the collection is not initialised anyway

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Everything except the array list is unneeded.

Fields are automatically initialized with their respective default value before the code inside the constructor is executed.

This code is equivalent:

```
public class CEConnection 
{ 
    private IDomain domain; 
    private IObjectStoreSet ost; 
    private ArrayList osNames; 
    private String domainName; 
    private bool isCredentialsEstablished; 

    // Constructor 
    public CEConnection() 
    { 
        osNames = new ArrayList(); 
    }
```

Comment: If you have several constructor, you can place the `new ArrayList()` next to the declaration to avoid code duplicates.

Comment: Is there maybe another reason they are doing this? Or could be there reason why some people would manually set objects = null in the constructor? I thought IBM people are one of the best programers on this planet, wondering why they did this...

Comment: @silla: IBM programmers are ordinary persons just like everyone else. That they are one of the best programmers in the world is a strange assumption - why should they? I guess that code was maybe written by someone coming from a different language where this kind of initialization was necessary.

Comment: @silla: Maybe they want maximum transparency. Maybe some people are coming from other languages where that matters. It doesn't hurt to initialize them explicitely anyway.

Comment: It *does* hurt: it makes the code larger and take longer to read, and in particular harder to skim.  I'd also recommend dropping the `private` keyword.

Comment: @EamonNerbonne why drop the private keyword?

Comment: @EamonNerbonne: I agree with the first part of your comment, but not with the last one. Making accessibility explicit is a good idea.

Comment: It's extraneous text that merely makes skimming the code harder.  It serves no purpose and indeed distracts from those members that _don't_ have default accessibility - it's just like setting values to their default value - pure boilerplate with no function whatsoever.

Comment: @EamonNerbonne: While I'd avoid assigning default values to fields that already have those default values, I disagree with you on accessibility, and the reason is consistency. No matter where it appears in your code, a field of a given type always has the default value for that type. But default accessibility changes depending on its location. Namely, the default accessibility of types at the namespace level is `internal`, but the default accessibilty for types (or anything else) that lie within another type is `private`.

Comment: @EamonNerbonne: Adding to Adam's comment: The accessability of fields is private in classes but public in structs.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: default accessibility of fields is always private; also in structs (unlike in C++).

Comment: @AdamRobinson: You're talking about accessibility for a _type_, not a field; the OP's example doesn't concern that.  I think the readability argument is especially strong for frequently occuring code such as fields, and I'm not making the case for types.  I think the default accessibility was chosen well in C#; there aren't any surprises here and there's no risk in omitting it - so I prefer not to draw attention to the accessibility since it's almost certainly less important that the rest of the code.

Comment: @AdamRobinson: For the sake of discussion concerning type accessiblity:  The default accessibility is minimal in the sense that it grants access only to the enclosing scope.  For classes defined in another class that means it doesn't additionally grant access to things outside its surrounding class; and for assembly-level classes that means it doesn't additionally grant access to classes outside of that assembly. I think the default was well chosen; even for types I'm OK with omitting accessibility keywords.  I don't think it's nearly as important as for fields, however.

Comment: Take a step back: less code is better code.  That extra keyword needs to be worth *something*.  Let's say there's a risk of confusion: does it matter?  If you omit `private` and someone's confused and tries to access it, they'll get a compile-time error (and likely even before the compile due to intellisense).  The default is quite safe: this isn't a minefield where we need to be extra wordy and very explicit to avoid confusion.  Furthermore, the rule is very simple and if you habitually omit accessibility people will very quickly figure it out.  Bonus: unusual public fields are more obvious.

Comment: @EamonNerbonne: Oh my, that's embarrassing. I mixed C++ and C# here.

Comment: @EamonNerbonne: I feel like we're splitting hairs here, but less code is better code *all things being equal*. Here, all things *aren't* equal. If I declare a class without accessibility at namespace/assembly level, use it, then end up moving it within a class, its accessibility changes. Obviously its overall signature has changed as well, but its local signature has not and now it's `private` instead of `internal`. Is this a big deal? No. Is it easily fixed? Yes. Is it *perfectly acceptable* to leave off accessibility and use the default? Sure, but for types I can't agree that it's *better*.

Comment: @Adam I agree that's it perfectly acceptable to include it on types as well.  I do feel there's a slight split-hair-width advantage to the less code variant; but it's not particularly relevant.  For fields, the code bloat is greater, and the additional clarity lesser; those really should omit accessibility.

Answer (score 3):

It's "alright" in the sense that it will not cause unexpected behavior, waste any resources, or cause your code to become less readable.

It's unnecessary, as all of those variables (other than `osNames`) will already have those values by the time the constructor is called. Unlike local variables, instance and static variables *always* have a value (even if that value is null), and thus to not require initialization before use.

Comment: Yup - objects gets the default value null, bools get the default value false, so asides from the list initialisation that constructor code is pretty pointless.

Answer (score 1):

It's all right to set it to any value whatsoever that will compile.

The real question is, "is this a meaningful and valid state to start **this** class in, considering the parameters passed to the constructor?" which in this case means no parameters.

That's the constructor's job, to put the class into a state that is:

1. Valid for the semantics of the class.
2. Relevant to the parameters, if any.

Anything that does that, is fine.

Anything that doesn't do that is a heavy (and hence quite possibly ill-advised) optimisation at best, a serious flaw at worse.

Relatedly, it is also the responsibility of any method or property that changes the state of the class, to leave it in a valid state.

Answer (score 0):

When a field variable is declared, it is automatically initialized to `default(T)`. This is null for reference variables, false for booleans and 0 for 'numeric' ValueTypes (Integer, Double, Decimal, ...)

Those initialisers are thus clutter. They just make the code longer.

Do note that default(T) for ArrayList is also null so you would still have to set that one to a new instance of ArrayList.